# Erro a ler se ficheiro . arff existe ou não

Tags: java

Estou a desenvolver um robot em JAVA juntamente com a framework Robocode e o WEKA. Sempre que tento verificar se o ficheiro ".arff" existe, dá-me sempre o mesmo erro.

> Round 1 initializing..
>
> Let the games begin!
>
> Preventing Interative_NEWVERSION.NewRobot_Interative* from access:
>   ("java.io.FilePermission"
>   "C:\Users\JoseDias\Documents\NetBeansProjects\InterativePower.arff"
>   "read"). You may only read files in your own root package directory.
>
> .Interative_NEWVERSION.NewRobot_Interative* has caused a security
>   violation. This robot has been banned and will not be allowed to
>   participate in battles.
>
> Interative_NEWVERSION.NewRobot_Interative*: Exception:
>   java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.io.FilePermission"
>   "C:\Users\JoseDias\Documents\NetBeansProjects\InterativePower.arff"
>   "read")

A linha seguinte, é a linha que uso para verificar se existe ou não o ficheiro numa dada localização.

```
@Override
public boolean datasetExists(String path) {

    File dc = new File(path);
  return   dc.exists();


}
```

Qual poderá ser o problema relacionado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, seu código está sem permissão para acessar o arquivo.

adcione as seguintes linhas abaixo da variavel de referencia dc:

```
    dc.setReadable(Boolean.FALSE);
    dc.setWritable(Boolean.FALSE);
    dc.setExecutable(Boolean.FALSE);
```

Por quê FALSE? R: porque ao definir false, você informa ao sistema que quer que todos tenham acesso ao arquivo. Se informar True, somente o owner do arquivo terá acesso, o que é estranho no contrário do padrão para casos boolean, mas tudo bem.

Fonte: https://develoraptor.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/manipulando-permissoes-de-arquivos-em-java/